# Webpack config issue

Tags: node.js, webpack, config

Hi i'm a super newbie about webpack but i spent something like 4 hours researching to fix my problem so I decided to post my issue here.
That's what my prompt diplay when i launch "webpack" command.

> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js 96:20 Critical dependency: the request
>   of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js 119:15 Critical dependency: the
>   request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/compile/index.js 13:21 Critical dependency: the
>   request of a dependency is an expression
>
> ERROR in .//pdf3json/pdfparser.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'fs' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\pdf3json'
>   @ .//pdf3json/pdfparser.js 5:9-22 @ ./~/pdf2text/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//download-file/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'fs' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\download-file'
>   @ .//download-file/index.js 1:9-22 @ ./~/download-pdf/index.js @
>   ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//request/lib/har.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'fs' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\request\lib'
>   @ .//request/lib/har.js 3:9-22 @ .//request/request.js @
>   .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//pdf3json/lib/pdf.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'fs' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\pdf3json\lib'
>   @ .//pdf3json/lib/pdf.js 3:9-22 @ .//pdf3json/pdfparser.js @
>   .//pdf2text/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//forever-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'net' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\forever-agent'
>   @ .//forever-agent/index.js 6:10-24 @ .//request/request.js @
>   .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//forever-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'tls' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\forever-agent'
>   @ .//forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24 @ .//request/request.js @
>   .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//pdf3json/package.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\pdf3json\package.json
>   Unexpected token (2:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "_args": [ | [ | { @ .//pdf3json/lib/pdf.js
>   11:13-39 @ .//pdf3json/pdfparser.js @ .//pdf2text/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'net' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
>   @ .//tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 32:10-24 @ .//request/lib/cookies.js @
>   .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//tough-cookie/package.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\tough-cookie\package.json
>   Unexpected token (2:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "_args": [ | [ | { @
>   .//tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 38:14-40 @ .//request/lib/cookies.js @
>   .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//mkdirp/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'fs' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\mkdirp'
>   @ .//mkdirp/index.js 2:9-22 @ .//download-file/index.js @
>   .//download-pdf/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//pdf3json/lib/ptixmlinject.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\pdf3json\lib'
>   @ .//pdf3json/lib/ptixmlinject.js 5:5-18 @ .//pdf3json/lib/pdf.js @
>   .//pdf3json/pdfparser.js @ ./~/pdf2text/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//tunnel-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'net' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
>   @ .//tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24 @ .//request/lib/tunnel.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ ./~/request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//tunnel-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'tls' in
>   'C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
>   @ .//tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24 @ .//request/lib/tunnel.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ ./~/request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in (webpack)//browserify-sign/browser/algorithms.json Module
>   parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\browserify-sign\browser\algorithms.json
>   Unexpected token (2:27) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "sha224WithRSAEncryption": { | "sign": "rsa", |
>   "hash": "sha224", @ (webpack)//browserify-sign/algos.js 1:17-53 @
>   (webpack)//crypto-browserify/index.js @ .//request/lib/helpers.js @
>   ./~/request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//mime-db/db.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\mime-db\db.json
>   Unexpected token (2:40) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "application/1d-interleaved-parityfec": { |
>   "source": "iana" | }, @ .//mime-db/index.js 11:17-37 @
>   .//mime-types/index.js @ .//request/request.js @ ./~/request/index.js
>   @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in (webpack)//diffie-hellman/lib/primes.json Module parse
>   failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\diffie-hellman\lib\primes.json
>   Unexpected token (2:11) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "modp1": { | "gen": "02", | "prime":
>   "ffffffffffffffffc90fdaa22168c234c4c6628b80dc1cd129024e088a67cc74020bbea63b139b22514a08798e3404ddef9519b3cd3a431b302b0a6df25f14374fe1356d6d51c245e485b576625e7ec6f44c42e9a63a3620ffffffffffffffff"
>   @ (webpack)//diffie-hellman/browser.js 2:13-41 @
>   (webpack)//crypto-browserify/index.js @ .//request/lib/helpers.js @
>   ./~/request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in (webpack)//browserify-sign/browser/curves.json Module parse
>   failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\browserify-sign\browser\curves.json
>   Unexpected token (2:16) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "1.3.132.0.10": "secp256k1", | "1.3.132.0.33":
>   "p224", | "1.2.840.10045.3.1.1": "p192", @
>   (webpack)//browserify-sign/browser/sign.js 7:13-37 @
>   (webpack)//browserify-sign/browser/index.js @
>   (webpack)//crypto-browserify/index.js @ .//request/lib/helpers.js @
>   .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in (webpack)//elliptic/package.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\elliptic\package.json
>   Unexpected token (2:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "_args": [ | [ | { @
>   (webpack)//elliptic/lib/elliptic.js 5:19-45 @
>   (webpack)//create-ecdh/browser.js @
>   (webpack)//crypto-browserify/index.js @ .//request/lib/helpers.js @
>   .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/afterRequest.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\afterRequest.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "afterRequest.json#", | "type": "object",
>   | "optional": true, @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 4:16-46 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/beforeRequest.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\beforeRequest.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "beforeRequest.json#", | "type": "object",
>   | "optional": true, @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 5:17-48 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/browser.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\browser.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "browser.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 6:11-36 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/cache.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\cache.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "cache.json#", | "properties": { |
>   "beforeRequest": { @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 7:9-32 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/cookie.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\cookie.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "cookie.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 9:10-34 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/creator.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\creator.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "creator.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 10:11-36 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/content.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\content.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "content.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 8:11-36 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/entry.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\entry.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "entry.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "optional": true, @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 11:9-32 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/har.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\har.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "har.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 12:7-28 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/header.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\header.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "header.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 13:10-34 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/log.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\log.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "log.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 14:7-28 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/page.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\page.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "page.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "optional": true, @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 15:8-30 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/pageTimings.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\pageTimings.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "pageTimings.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "properties": { @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 16:15-44 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/postData.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\postData.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "postData.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "optional": true, @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 17:12-38 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/query.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\query.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "query.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 18:9-32 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/request.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\request.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "request.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 19:11-36 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/response.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\response.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "response.json#", | "type": "object", |
>   "required": [ @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 20:12-38 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//har-schema/lib/timings.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\timings.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "timings.json#", | "required": [ | "send",
>   @ .//har-schema/lib/index.js 21:11-36 @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-04.json Module parse
>   failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\ajv\lib\refs\json-schema-draft-04.json
>   Unexpected token (2:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id": "htp://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
>   | "$schema": "htp://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#", |
>   "description": "Core schema meta-schema", @ .//ajv/lib/ajv.js
>   385:23-66 @ .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @
>   .//request/lib/har.js @ .//request/request.js @ .//request/index.js @
>   ./main.js
>
> ERROR in .//ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-v5.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\ajv\lib\refs\json-schema-v5.json
>   Unexpected token (2:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { | "id":
>   "htps://raw.githubusercontent.com/epoberezkin/ajv/master/lib/refs/json-schema-v5.json#",
>   | "$schema": "htp://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#", |
>   "description": "Core schema meta-schema (v5 proposals)", @
>   .//ajv/lib/v5.js 20:21-58 @ .//ajv/lib/ajv.js @
>   .//har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js @ .//request/lib/har.js @
>   .//request/request.js @ ./~/request/index.js @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in (webpack)//parse-asn1/aesid.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\parse-asn1\aesid.json
>   Unexpected token (1:25) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | {"2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.1": "aes-128-ecb", |
>   "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2": "aes-128-cbc", | "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.3":
>   "aes-128-ofb", @ (webpack)//parse-asn1/index.js 2:12-35 @
>   (webpack)//public-encrypt/privateDecrypt.js @
>   (webpack)//public-encrypt/browser.js @
>   (webpack)//crypto-browserify/index.js @ .//request/lib/helpers.js @
>   ./~/request/index.js @ ./main.js

That's my "webpack.config.js".

```
module.exports = { entry: './main.js', output: { filename: './bundle.js' } };
```

I know that's a lot of things to read : ( but i really appreciate everything.

I modified config file into this.

```
module.exports = { entry: './main.js', output: { filename: './bundle.js' }, target: 'node' };
```

Prompt display this.

> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js 96:20 Critical dependency: the request
>   of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js 119:15 Critical dependency: the
>   request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/compile/index.js 13:21 Critical dependency: the
>   request of a dependency is an expression
>
> ERROR in ./~/pdf3json/package.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\pdf3json\package.json
>   Unexpected token (2:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "_args": [ |     [ |       {  @
>   ./~/pdf3json/lib/pdf.js 11:13-39  @ ./~/pdf3json/pdfparser.js  @
>   ./~/pdf2text/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/tough-cookie/package.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\tough-cookie\package.json
>   Unexpected token (2:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "_args": [ |     [ |       {  @
>   ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 38:14-40  @ ./~/request/lib/cookies.js 
>   @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/hawk/package.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\hawk\package.json
>   Unexpected token (2:9) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "_args": [ |     [ |       {  @
>   ./~/hawk/lib/utils.js 14:11-37  @ ./~/hawk/lib/index.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/mime-db/db.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\mime-db\db.json
>   Unexpected token (2:40) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "application/1d-interleaved-parityfec": { |
>   "source": "iana" |   },  @ ./~/mime-db/index.js 11:17-37  @
>   ./~/mime-types/index.js  @ ./~/request/request.js  @
>   ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/afterRequest.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\afterRequest.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "afterRequest.json#", |   "type":
>   "object", |   "optional": true,  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 4:16-46
>   @ ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/beforeRequest.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\beforeRequest.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "beforeRequest.json#", |   "type":
>   "object", |   "optional": true,  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 5:17-48
>   @ ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/browser.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\browser.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "browser.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 6:11-36  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/cache.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\cache.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "cache.json#", |   "properties": { |
>   "beforeRequest": {  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 7:9-32  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/content.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\content.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "content.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 8:11-36  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/cookie.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\cookie.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "cookie.json#", |   "type": "object", | 
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 9:10-34  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/creator.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\creator.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "creator.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 10:11-36  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/entry.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\entry.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "entry.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "optional": true,  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 11:9-32  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/har.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\har.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "har.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 12:7-28  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/header.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\header.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "header.json#", |   "type": "object", | 
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 13:10-34  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/log.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\log.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "log.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 14:7-28  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/page.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\page.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "page.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "optional": true,  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 15:8-30  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/pageTimings.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\pageTimings.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "pageTimings.json#", |   "type":
>   "object", |   "properties": {  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 16:15-44 
>   @ ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/postData.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\postData.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "postData.json#", |   "type": "object",
>   |   "optional": true,  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 17:12-38  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/request.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\request.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "request.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 19:11-36  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js
>
> ERROR in ./~/har-schema/lib/query.json Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\stagista11\Desktop\Progetto\video-stats\node_modules\har-schema\lib\query.json
>   Unexpected token (2:6) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | { |   "id": "query.json#", |   "type": "object", |
>   "required": [  @ ./~/har-schema/lib/index.js 18:9-32  @
>   ./~/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js  @ ./~/request/lib/har.js  @
>   ./~/request/request.js  @ ./~/request/index.js  @ ./main.js

Comment: Can you try adding `target: 'node'` to the webpack config? So it looks like this: `module.exports = { entry: './main.js', output: { filename: './bundle.js' }, target: 'node' };`

Comment: It displays some errors anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop webpack loading node modules using the [webpack-node-externals](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) module to get rid of `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

Then install the [json-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader) which causes the module parse failures:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = { 
  entry: './main.js', 
  output: { filename: './bundle.js' }, 
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
  rules: [
     {
       test: /\.json$/,
       use: 'json-loader'
     }
   ] 
};
```

Please post your package.json and dir structure if this doesn't work.

Comment: Excuse me for the nonsense question: It's possible to convert a node.js script ("like mine") into a client side script?

Comment: I've not seen your script but a module which runs a JavaScript file anywhere is known as UMD: https://github.com/umdjs/umd. Your browser and node.js have different runtimes but as long as you understand the browser doesn't have libraries like 'fs', 'http' and 'path' and that node.js doesn't have global.btoa and global.atob it is easy enough.

Comment: Man you're THE GENIOUS. So i can tranform every node script into client side script with, for example, browserify but... i can't use module like fs http and path isn't it?

Comment: So if i want to use a library that downloads pdfs and process them, I have to do that server side and pass the result with ajax to the client, isn't it?

Comment: Browserify is still based on CommonJS not UMD but as you'll read a UMD can be imported into a common or require.js (AMD) or without one by binding to the window or global object. Typically, you'll see authors use webpack for applications and rollup for plugins (https://github.com/rollup/rollup) - rollup has some nice features for outputting UMD.

Answer (score 3):

Add below code to webpack.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
target: 'node'
};
```

Comment: This resolved my issue: `./node_modules/request/lib/har.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`.